# How to prevent git from asking for login again and again

Tags: git, authentication

I just created a new git repository and I can't push for the first time over SSH without typing my login again.

It asks for my login credentials even though `ssh -T git@github.com` says I'm authenticated.

Comment: this question was created to share the content in this tweet: https://twitter.com/_mkos/status/952518489696362496

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two types of Github or Gitlab links:

### SSH Links

- They have the following format: `git@github.com:{USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY}.git`
- You have to add an SSH key to the server (Github in our case) to be able to use them.
- Once you add your SSH key, you will not be asked for password (since authentication is handled via the SSH key). If you want to work on multiple computers, you have to set up each computer with the SSH key.

### HTTPS Links

- They have the following format: `https://github.com/{USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY}.git`
 - They do not require any additional settings, as opposed to the SSH link.
 - They do not handle authentication for you, hence they will always ask for password.

You can re-set your remote URL with the following command: `git remote set-url origin {LINK}`. When you open Github, and click on **Clone or download**, notice the **Use SSH** or **Use HTTPS** links. That will provide you with the correct link for your use-case.

For quick and dirty work, just one push and you're done, or when you're on a borrowed laptop/school computer, HTTPS works great. If you want to push a lot, or you're working from your private computer, SSH setup is much more convenient.

See the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) on how to add your SSH key.

### EDIT: Github Deprecated Basic Auth over HTTPS

Github has deprecated HTTPS Basic Auth method as per their [announcement](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/). If you want to clone repositories without creating an SSH key, Github recommends the personal access token, which is a generated token that will act as your password.

The advantage of using a personal access token is that if the token gets stolen, you can easily revoke the token at any point while your account is not compromised. The token gets access only to repositories you grant it.

The disadvantage of using a personal access token is that the token is not easily memorable (by design), since the token is in the format of a long string of numbers and letters (e.g. `a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1`).